# Cannot convert from an IEnumerable<T> to an ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I have defined the following:

```
public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

When I run this code:

```
Items = _item.Get("001");
```

I get the following message:

```
Error   3   
Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Storage.Models.Item>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Storage.Models.Item>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong. I am very confused about the 
difference between Enumerable, Collections and using the ToList()

**Added information**

Later in my code I have the following:

```
for (var index = 0; index < Items.Count(); index++)
```

Would I be okay to define Items as an IEnumerable?

Comment: Can you provide more information on the type of _item and the signature of Get(string) (specifically return type)?

Comment: Why not change the type like this? `public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }` Do you have any special reason to have it as `ICollection`?

Comment: IEnumerable<T> Get(string pk);

Answer (score 145, accepted):

`ICollection<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` so to assign the result of

```
IEnumerable<T> Get(string pk)
```

to an `ICollection<T>` there are two ways.

```
// 1. You know that the referenced object implements `ICollection<T>`,
//    so you can use a cast
ICollection<T> c = (ICollection<T>)Get("pk");

// 2. The returned object can be any `IEnumerable<T>`, so you need to 
//    enumerate it and put it into something implementing `ICollection<T>`. 
//    The easiest is to use `ToList()`:
ICollection<T> c = Get("pk").ToList();
```

The second options is more flexible, but has a much larger performance impact. Another option is to store the result as an `IEnumerable<T>` unless you need the extra functionality added by the `ICollection<T>` interface.

### Additional Performance Comment

The loop you have

```
for (var index = 0; index < Items.Count(); index++)
```

works on an `IEnumerable<T>` but it is inefficient; each call to `Count()` requires a *complete* enumeration of all elements. Either use a collection and the `Count` property (without the parenthesis) or convert it into a foreach loop:

```
foreach(var item in Items)
```

Comment: What is the additional functionality added by ICollection?

Comment: [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) can be manipulated (see the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) for details), while an `IEnumerable<T>` can only be enumerated.

Comment: I need to have something where I can run different LINQ queries. I don't need to add or do anything like that to the list. Does that mean I would be better off with ICollection.

Comment: LINQ works on `IEnumerable<T>` so `IEnumerable<T>` is enough in that case.

Answer (score 39):

You cannot convert directly from `IEnumerable<T>` to `ICollection<T>`. You can use `ToList` method of `IEnumerable<T>` to convert it to `ICollection<T>`

`someICollection = SomeIEnumerable.ToList();`

Comment: This works for me. But is it a good idea for me to convert or would I be better to use IEnumerable as the type for Items. If I use IEnumerable am I making it so I can do more actions on Items if needed later in my program?

Comment: ICollection already implements IEnumerable. If you are concerned about the available actions I think you should go for ICollection. It is better if you can read the actual difference between the two and then decide what actually you want to use

Comment: I am trying to understand what advantages I would have if I used ToList(). Once I have the data I would like to run LINQ queries against Items.

Comment: ToList() will work but as you have stated in your comments Get() returns an ICollection, so really you just need to do a cast to ICollection<T>, or better yet, change the return signature of Get to ICollection<T>. Using ToList or ToArray will work, but it will also incur an unnecessary create memory / copy operation

Comment: You can run LINQ queries against both IEnumerable and ICollection. Advantages.. one I know right now is the Count ICollection maintains count and IEnumerable returns result by calculating how many items it has. ICollection provides additional remove method which Ienumerables doesn't

Comment: "You cannot convert directly from IEnumerable<T> to ICollection<T>"  Be careful.  If an ICollection is returned from a method as an IEnumerable, it can be explicitly cast back to an ICollection and updated.

Answer (score 1):

Pending more information on the question:

*please provide more information on the type of item and the signature of Get*

Two things you can try are:

- To cast the return value of _item.Get to (ICollection)
- secondly to use _item.Get("001").ToArray() or _item.Get("001").ToList()

Please note the second will incur a performance hit for the array copy. If the signature (return type) of Get is not an ICollection then the first will not work, if it is not IEnumerable then the second will not work.

---

Following your clarification to question and in comments, I would personally declare the returning type of _item.Get("001") to ICollection. This means you won't have to do any casting or conversion (via ToList / ToArray) which would involve an unnecessary create/copy operation.

```
// Leave this the same
public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

// Change function signature here:
// As you mention Item uses the same underlying type, just return an ICollection<T>
public ICollection<Item> Get(string value); 

// Ideally here you want to call .Count on the collectoin, not .Count() on 
// IEnumerable, as this will result in a new Enumerator being created 
// per loop iteration
for (var index = 0; index < Items.Count(); index++)
```

Best regards,

Comment: The signature is: IEnumerable<T> Get(string pk);   Items is used to hold the Item records that are returned. Later on I iterate through these to create a report. I would be okay to use anything that works. What do you think the best type of datatype would be ?

Comment: I would suggest changing the datatype of Items to IEnumerable<T> to match Get, or changing the return type of Get to ICollection<T> to match Items. I assume these two are the same underlying type just declared differently? IF they are the same type you want to avoid using ToList() or ToArray() as that performs an unnecessary memory allocation and array copy. If they are not the same type you have to  do some conversion

Comment: I added to the question to show where I am later using Items. You are correct when saying the same underlying type.

Comment: Ok, then I would just change the return type of Get, as then you don't need to do any conversion (via ToList / ToArray, which is slow), or casting. Hope this helps :)