# Count method or property for an IList

Tags: c#

Thanks for help with explaining to me about IList and IEnumerable. I have marked that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692742/cannot-convert-from-an-ienumerablet-to-an-icollectiont/) as answered. Now I have a request for just a bit more information.

I have code like this:

```
for (var index = 0; index < Model.Items.Count(); index++)
```

It was suggested in a previous post that it's not efficient as the Count() is a method and it gets executed many times. I tried the following:

```
for (var index = 0; index < Model.Items.Count; index++)
```

This seems to work.

Can someone please confirm there's a difference. Both work so I am not 100 % sure.

Would the following be the most efficient? Does the foreach need an IList or and IEnumerable?

```
foreach(var item in Items)
```

Comment: Please put link to your previous Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Count()` method call actually calls the static [`Enumerable.Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method. This is optimized for `IList` implementations to use the property - but this requires a dynamic type check, and still ends up going through to the property - so using the property is certainly more efficient. In .NET 3.5 it only optimizes for `ICollection<T>`, whereas in .NET 4 it optimizes for the non-generic `ICollection` as well. See [my Edulinq blog post on `Count`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-7-count-and-longcount.aspx) for more details.

As for the last bit of your question: a `foreach` loop may or may not be more efficient, but it would be more *readable* in my view, which is rather more important. I would definitely use `foreach` unless you really need the index of each entry.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Does the foreach require an IList or IEnumerable?

Comment: @Samantha2: It doesn't actually require either, strictly speaking, but `IEnumerable` (or `IEnumerable<T>`) are enough to guarantee that you can use `foreach`.

Answer (score 6):

`Count()` extension method works for all objects that support `IEnumerable`, and since `IEnumerable` itself does not have any means of reporting item count, it *may have* to iterate over `IEnumerable` instance using it's `IEnumerator`, which can be a real performance hit if called many times.

However, if you look into `Count()` implementation, you'll see that it is optimized for `ICollection` types (both generic and non-generic, at least in FW4.0, meaning `IList` and `IList<T>` are also optimized), and if your object implements `ICollection` (which reports item count in `Count` property), `Count()` method returns item count without iterating through collection. That's why you don't see performance difference. Nevertheless, if you know that you have `ICollection` or `IList` instance, why not get `Count` property directly and be independent of `Count()` method implementation?

Also, remember that you can cache return value of `Count()` method in a variable to suppress multiple calls:

```
var count = Model.Items.Count();
for(var index = 0; index < count; index++) { }
```