# How can I use LINQ to populate a collection inside a class?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
     foreach (string applicationName in applicationNames)
     {
     _uow.Applications.Add(
        new Application 
        { 
            Name = applicationName, 
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
            TestAccounts = (from  testAccountName in testAccountNames
                            select new TestAccount
                            { 
                               Name = testAccountName , 
                               ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now 
                           })
        });
     }
```

The problem with this is that it gives me an error in the VS2012 IDE on the select. Here it says:

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Relational.Models.TestAccount>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Relational.Models.TestAccount>'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?
```

Here is the Application class:

```
public partial class Application
{
    public Application()
    {
        this.TestAccounts = new List<TestAccount>();
    }

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot convert from an IEnumerable<T> to an ICollection<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692742/cannot-convert-from-an-ienumerablet-to-an-icollectiont)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
 foreach (string applicationName in applicationNames)
 {
 _uow.Applications.Add(
    new Application 
    { 
        Name = applicationName, 
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
        TestAccounts = (from  testAccountName in testAccountNames
                        select new TestAccount
                        { 
                           Name = testAccountName , 
                           ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now 
                       }).ToList()
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a cast to `IList<TestAccount>`.

```
    { 
        Name = applicationName, 
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
        TestAccounts = (from  testAccountName in testAccountNames
                        select new TestAccount
                        { 
                           Name = testAccountName , 
                           ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now 
                       }).ToList()     // <-- try this
    });
```