# How to convert from ICollection to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

In the below code the return statement is throwing exception.

```
private IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> GetDomains()
{
    ICollection<string> domains = new List<string>();

    // Querying the current Forest for the domains within.
    foreach (Domain d in Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains)
    {
        domains.Add(d.Name);
    }

    return domains;  //doesn't work
}
```

What could be the possible resolution to this issue?

Comment: You're trying to return a string collection when the return type of the method is an IEnumerable of DirectoryEntry

Comment: Your sample makes no sense - you try to return `IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry>` but instead returning collection of strings... There is some explanation missing of what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert from an IEnumerable<T> to an ICollection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692742/cannot-convert-from-an-ienumerablet-to-an-icollectiont)

Answer (score 2):

Redefine your method as

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetDomains()
{
    ...
}
```

since you're wanting a list of `string` and not `Domains` or `DirectoryEntry`.  (assumed since you're adding "d.Name")

Also, it would be much easier to just use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<string> domains = Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Select(x => x.Name);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<string>`, and it won't waste extra memory creating a separate list.

Comment: this is _unnecessary_ and also not a problem,if the return type is IEnumerable<string> returning a list of string would be fine. the actual problem is return type of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Set the type of domains to `IList<string>`
or do as Nathan suggests:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetDomains()
{
  return Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Select(x => x.Name);
}
```

Comment: You can also use .Cast<YourListType>()

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this works too:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetDomains()
{
  return Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Cast<string>();
}
```

Where the cast type equals the type of your IEnumerable.

Answer (score -3):

`ICollection<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can probably just cast it:

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```