# How to use a lambda expression to return Collection

Tags: c#

Given below error is throwing type casting error

```
public Collection<AssignedReadingScheduleDTO> GetAssignedReadingScheduleList(int substationId, DateTime getLastSyncDate, out string errorMessage)
{
    AssignedReadingScheduleDTO filter = new AssignedReadingScheduleDTO();
    Collection<AssignedReadingScheduleDTO> colAsgnReadSchedulList = null;
    MessageServiceClass messageService = new MessageServiceClass();
    ExceptionCodeDTO errorMessageCode = null; errorMessage = string.Empty;
    AssignedReadingSchedule_IDA daAsgnreadingScheduleList = (new AssignedReadingScheduleDA()).CreateDBObject();
    try
    {
        filter.LocalCntrID = substationId;
        filter.StationType = 2;
        colAsgnReadSchedulList = new Collection<AssignedReadingScheduleDTO>();
        colAsgnReadSchedulList = daAsgnreadingScheduleList.GetAssignedReadingScheduleList(0, Int32.MaxValue, filter, out errorMessageCode).Where(x=>x.UpdateOn >= getLastSyncDate) as Collection<AssignedReadingScheduleDTO>;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessageCode.ReferenceNumber = messageService.GetExceptionRefNumber(ex);
    }
    return colAsgnReadSchedulList;
}
```

Comment: What is the error _exactly_? On which line?

Comment: colAsgnReadSchedulList = daAsgnreadingScheduleList.GetAssignedReadingScheduleList(0, Int32.MaxValue, filter, out errorMessageCode).Where(x=>x.UpdateOn >= getLastSyncDate) as Collection<AssignedReadingScheduleDTO>; getting null value at this line

Comment: and getting type casting error when i used given below code colAsgnReadSchedulList = (Collection<AssignedReadingScheduleDTO>)daAsgnreadingScheduleList.GetAssignedReadingScheduleList(0, Int32.MaxValue, filter, out errorMessageCode).Where(x=>x.UpdateOn >= getLastSyncDate);

Comment: @khushboosingh - update the question with this info. Its insanely hard to read that much code, unformatted, in a comment

Comment: How I Can Return Collection using lamda expression

Comment: Related: [Cannot convert from an IEnumerable<T> to an ICollection<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692742/cannot-convert-from-an-ienumerablet-to-an-icollectiont)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly create a `Collection<T>` with the standard Linq methods.   The only concrete types* the build-in Linq methods can create are `List<T>` (via `ToList`) and array instances (via `ToArray`).  Here's some options:

- Create your own extension method `ToCollection` that will create a `Collection<T>` (or find a third-party library that has such a method)
- Loop through the results and add each item to the collection.
- Create a `List<T>` and use the `Collection<T>` constructor that takes an `IList<T>`
- Change your return type to `ICollection<T>` (or `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`)

---

*<sub>I'm not counting projections or transformations like `ToDictionary` and `ToDataTable`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, except that the Linq Where statement returns an IEnumerable of the type inside the collection you are querying.
So the simpler way to create your Collection is cycle the IEnumerable returned by the Where and add the elements to a new Collection or if the Generic Collection has an AddRange method, use it to add the IEnumerable to your collection.