# Convert IEnumerable<string> to ICollection<string>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have both an `IEnumerable<string>` and an `ICollection<string>` passed in as arguments to a method.  Within the method, I want to concat some values to the `ICollection<string>` and reassign the return value from the concat invocation back onto the `ICollection<string>` passed in.  My question is, what is the most effective way to do so?

> Cannot convert source type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'` to target type `'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>'`.

```
void DoSomething(IEnumerable<string> values, ICollection<string> otherValues)
{
    // Ideally, I could chain after the Concat and get my ICollection<string>.
    otherValues = otherValues.Concat(GetConcatValues());

    // Remaining source left out for brevity...
}
```

I fully understand the issue with the conversion and that `ICollection<string>` inherits `IEnumerable<string>`.  Additionally, I know that the .Concat call returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and not the desired `ICollection<string>`.

I simply want to know if there is a one line extension method that already exists that will knowingly convert this to the collection I want it as?  Also, I just realized that I said `IEnumerable<string>` and `ICollection<string>` like a million times...

Comment: You could just use `ToList()`

Comment: Questions has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8692796/5622895

Comment: I assume you don't want the concatenated values to `otherValues` to be visible outisde the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have to convert to one of the classes implementing `ICollection` interface, calling `ToList` on your `IEnumerable<string>` will do the trick:

```
otherValues = otherValues.Concat(GetConcatValues()).ToList();
```

**Note:** Assigning to `otherValues` has no effect in the caller, because it is not passed by reference or by an `out` parameter. Assuming that you are passing a modifiable collection into the method, you could do this to populate it with the data coming from `Concat`:

```
foreach(var s in GetConcatValues()) {
    otherValues.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was rather simple...

Comment: @DavidPine I am not sure if the first solution is what you want. Please see the note in the edit.

Comment: In you 2'nd solution you are modifying the collection being iterated (`otherValues`). Also if it would have worked the values of `otherValues` would have been repeated twice which I don't think is what the op intended.

Comment: @Magnus Ah, you are right - I missed that part. I added a `ToList()` call to prevent that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think it should just be: `foreach(var s in GetConcatValues()) otherValues.Add(s);`

Comment: @Magnus You are right again! Thanks!