# How do I convert IEnumerable to Collection with linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections, type-conversion

I am populating a partial view with product from my ProductViewModel.  When the model comes back we have...

```
var viewModel = _productAgent.GetProductsByCatalog(catalogId);
```

viewModel is a Collection of ProductViewModel

I am using linq to limit the size of the collection to the top 10 products orderby createDate desc like so...

```
var newList = (from p in viewModel
           //from pf in p.DomainObjectFields
           select p).Distinct().OrderByDescending(d => d.CreateDate).Take(10);
```

and I try to load the partial...

```
return PartialView("_ProductGrid", viewModel);
```

The problem is newList is IEnumerable  It needs to be a collection and I do not know how to convert it OR if I'm taking the correct approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert from an IEnumerable<T> to an ICollection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692742/cannot-convert-from-an-ienumerablet-to-an-icollectiont)

Comment: Maybe this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692742/cannot-convert-from-an-ienumerablet-to-an-icollectiont

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the extension methods `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`, etc.

```
var newList = viewModel
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreateDate)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

**Update**

If you want to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to `Collection<T>` you can use the overload of the constructor of the class `Collection<T>` like this:

```
Collection<ProductViewModel> newList = new Collection<ProductViewModel>(viewModel
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreateDate)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList());
```

Comment: You can also use the linq extension method `AsEnumerable` if wanna keep it lazy.

Comment: You could also say that from p select p is... well, not really needed

Comment: @Camilo ... LINQ isn't something I write everyday...how would I write this more efficiently?

Comment: @tony I edited the answer so it makes more sense from a LINQ perspective. But in terms of efficiency, it would depend on how you retrieved those viewmodels

Comment: ok...that really cleans it up nice but I still can't convert newlist to a collection

Comment: @tony please define collection. What type exactly do you want to convert it to?

Comment: before the linq executes the "viewModel" is a Collection of ProductViewModel...after the LINQ populates "newList"; newList is List<ProductViewModel> where it needs to be "Collection of"

Comment: @tony I updated the answer. Let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Deadznone...thank you for the solution...I would not have thought to do that in a million years!  Awesome job :)

Answer (score -3):

You could try `newList.toList();`